# Random point configuration from the Poincare disk model gives division by zero problem near boundary

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to select points uniformly at random from the Poincare disk model of hyperbolic geometry:

```
showpts[t_] := Module[{}, reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 0.99];
  pts = RandomPointConfiguration[
    InhomogeneousPoissonPointProcess[
     Function[4/(t^2 (1 - ((#1)^2 + (#2)^2))^2)], 2], reg];
  Show[RegionPlot[reg], ListPlot[pts]]]
showpts[1]
```

But this returns with a division by zero problem,

[image]

If I run this with a disk radius of 0.91 I get the same problem. I would have thought that would easily avoid the problem of the point process density being undefined at the boundary of the disk.

The code works with a disk radius of 0.9,

```
showpts[t_] := Module[{}, reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9];
  pts = RandomPointConfiguration[
    InhomogeneousPoissonPointProcess[
     Function[4/(t^2 (1 - ((#1)^2 + (#2)^2))^2)], 2], reg];
  Show[RegionPlot[reg], ListPlot[pts]]]
showpts[1]
```

[image]

Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: Guessing at the fringes there can be machine double computations that underflow to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WorkingPrecision -> 80` seems work.

```
t = 1;
 RandomPointConfiguration[
 InhomogeneousPoissonPointProcess[
  Function[4/(t^2 (1 - ((#1)^2 + (#2)^2))^2)], 2], Disk[{0, 0}, .95], 
 WorkingPrecision -> 80]
Show[Graphics[Circle[]], ListPlot[%]]
```

[image]